# GC consideration of many Models having reference to same service

Tags: java, kotlin, oop, architecture, garbage-collection

I have a case where a client can select multiple payment methods to pay with.
In order to place an order, we use a manual capture flow :

1. we authorize payment with the payment Gateway (Stripe, etc.)
2. we then receive a "payment id"
3. we make orders with our suppliers
4. if everything is ok, we can "capture"(finalize) the payment.
   otherwise, we release the payment.

Upon every placeOrder() call, I create a Payment model that:

1. references a single gateway service (injected to the api class), and then
2. upon calling "authorizeFunds()", the model changes its own "paymentId" field based on the result.

**Problem**

My only 2 concerns are :

1. *Garbage collection*:
   after a certain scale, wouldn't placerOrder() result in a lot of Payment objects that could not be garbage collected because they all have a reference to the gateway object?
2. *Model self manipulates inner field*:
   the fact the authorizeFunds() changes the field inside the Payment method - is it a good practice? Or are there consideration that I have missed?

Gateway Interface :

```
interface IPaymentGateway {
     suspend fun authorizeFunds(amount: String, currency: String, clientAuthId: String)
     suspend fun captureFunds(paymentId: String)
     suspend fun releaseFunds(paymentId: String)
}
```

Payment Model :

```
data class PaymentRequest(
    private val paymentGateway: IPaymentGateway,
    private val clientAuthId: String, 
    private val amount: String, 
    private val currency: String, 
    private var paymentId: String? = null 
) {
    fun isPaymentAuthorized(): Boolean {
        return paymentId != null
    }
    
    suspend fun authorizeFunds() {
        paymentId = paymentGateway.authorizeFunds(amount, currency, clientAuthId)
    }
    
    suspend fun captureFunds(): Boolean {
        return if (paymentId != null) {
            paymentGateway.captureFunds(paymentId)
        } else false
    }
    
    suspend fun releaseFunds(): Boolean {
        return if (paymentId != null) {
            paymentGateway.releaseFunds(paymentId)
        } else false
    }
}
```

The API with the placeOrder func:

```
class OrderApiService(
    val creditGateway: CreditGateway
    val payPalGateway: PaypalGateway,
    val repo: Repository
) {
    
    suspend fun placeOrder(paymentMethod: PaymentMethod, clientAuthId: String) {
        
        val order = repo.getOrderDetails(...)
        
        val payment = if (paymentMethod == PaymentMethod.PAYPAL) {
            // this will probably be generated from some payment service
            PaymentRequest(
                paymentGateway = payPalGateway,
                clientAuthId = clientAuthId,
                amount = order.amount,
                currency = order.currency,
            )
        } else {
            // ...
        }
        
        // make some orders with the suppliers...

        // 1. auth 
        payment.authorizeFunds()
        
        // 2. capture/release
        if (payment.isAuthorized()) {
            payment.captureFunds()
        } else {
            payment.releaseFunds()
        }
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Having a reference _to_ another object doesn't stop the first object from being garbage collected.  Only being referenced _from_ another object stops garbage collection.